# Can a WinForms program be run from command line?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, console-application

I would like to know if its is possible to have a winforms program that can also be run from the command line?

What I want to do is create a simple Winform that sends out an email. This program will be called from a console application that I already have.  But I also want to be able to run this program separately as well.

Is this possible?

If so, how can I run this program from my existing console application?

I am using .NET 4.5 in C#.

Comment: Do you want your Form to appear if it's called from CommandLine or should it do some work and don't show anything?

Comment: yes you can, if you want to add arguments to the exe when loading look at the Program.cs which contains the Main method.

Comment: @Tomtom - No, I would like the form to be hidden if run from the command line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of course it is possible, if you have built your winform app using the default settings, then search the `Program.cs` file and you will find the Main method.

You could change this method signature in this way

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         // Here I suppose you pass, as first parameter, this flag to signal 
         // your intention to process from command line, 
         // of course change it as you like
         if(args != null && args[0] == "/autosendmail")
         {
              // Start the processing of your command line params
              ......
              // At the end the code falls out of the main and exits    
         }
         else
         {
             // No params passed on the command line, open the usual UI interface
             Application.EnableVisualStyles();
             Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
             Application.Run(new frmMain());

         }
    }
```

I have forgot to answer the other part of your question, how to launch this winapp from your console application. It is really easy with the Process class in the System.Diagnostics namespace and the [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to fine tune the environment of the launched application

```
   ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
   psi.FileName = "YourWinApp.exe";
   psi.Arguments = "/autosendmail destination@email.com  ..... "; // or just a filename with data
   psi.WorkingDirectory = "."; // or directory where you put the winapp 
   Process.Start(psi);
```

Given the numerous information needed to send a mail, I suggest to store all the destination addresses and texts to send in a file and pass just the filename to your winapp

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.SendMail();
        Application.Run();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This will hide the Win form and you can still call any of the public methods of Win Form.

Answer (score 2):

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "youApplicationPath",
    Arguments = "balh blah blah",
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
};
Process p = new Process { StartInfo = psi };
p.Start();
```

Get the arguments by:

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you would like to start windows form from existing console application.  If that is the case then you will need to call it from console application like this:

```
Process.Start("YourWindowsApp.exe");
```

You can user [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to have more control about how to start your process.  For instance you can send additional arguments, or you can start your window as hidden.  Here is an example on how to use ProcessStartInfo.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "YourWindowsApp.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = "arguments for YourWindowsApp.exe";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to run a different application (like your winform.exe) from your first application (your console app) in C#, put this line in your code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("...\winform.exe"); // file path should be exact!
```

the `winform.exe` here actually will be your executable file that should be in `release` or `debug` folder inside `YourProjectFolder\bin`. you can double-click the executable file to run it manually!